# How do I modify a tree to get edge weights less than the vertex's values?

Tags: tree

So, this question goes like this:

Given a weighted tree with values assigned to each node, you are allowed to do 2 free and 1 paid operation:

Free

1. Swap any two vertices
2. Swap any two edges

Paid

1. Change the value assigned to a vertex

The question asks us to report the minimum number of paid operations required to have a resulting tree where:

> Weight of edges <= Value written on the adjacent vertices

For eg:

> Vertex 1: Value 1
>
> Vertex 2: Value 5
>
> Vertex 3: Value 10

Given the tree is:

1 ---(4)--- 2 ---(7)--- 3

where 4 and 7 are edge weights, the best solution would be to vertices nodes 1 and 2 (operation i) and change the value of node 2 to >= 7 (operation iii).

Thus the answer would be 1.

I can't think of an efficient solution or a coding implementation to this question. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any help would be strongly appreciated!